# Copy & Paste to the next empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to copy and paste cell value in another sheet but it replaces the value in the same cell on the other sheet.

I need it to count the columns and continue to paste the value in the next cell to the right.

The code below worked on prior spreadsheets.

```vb
Col = Sheet3.Cells(11, 11).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 1

Sheet3.Cells(11, 11) = Sheet2.Range("E10")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Col" variable.

```
Col = Sheet3.Cells(11, 11).CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + 1

Sheet3.Cells(11, Col) = Sheet2.Range("E10")
```